# Does Phonegap Currently support full screen tablet apps?

Tags: android, cordova

I understand that Phonegap is actually Cordova (sp?) now.  The information I've found doesn't seem to answer the question about full screen tablet apps.  I've seen apps designed for smartphones that can appear on the Tablets, like the iPad but I am not going for that.
I had seen something about a magazine application using phonegap and I could use something like that.  I'm just wondering how it is going to appear in the larger screen tablet devices.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you mean full screen as in removing status bars and on screen controls in android, the answer gets a bit more complicated, but that's an issue with android rather than phonegap.